Prevent or Warn About Changing of (Conditional) Formatting
I am maintaining a large table that contains very important conditional formatting specific to certain columns. The table is regularly edited by many people, both using the standalone desktop version of Excel and the web/online version in browsers. I need to ensure that the conditional formatting will never be changed by anyone but me (or another maintainer).
I have tried protecting the sheet and removing the checkmark for formatting changes. Unfortunately, it seems some users mess with the formatting by simply copying whole cells and pasting them into a different line or column (instead of pasting values only).
How can I either prevent such formatting changes from happening when others paste something (especially in the web version), or at least create clear visual signs that the user did something wrong when it happens (e.g. by creating a broad conditional-formatting rule that is sensitive to the position of the cells, such that if a cell covered by this rule is copied to a different column and/or row, its red fill or other marker kicks in)? It would be great if it also affects any similar changes produced by other UI-sugar means (corner-dragging, pressing ^D or ^R &c.).

I'm afraid that effective protection of conditional formatting is difficult to achieve. Note that when you record changes to conditional formatting, the recorder deletes all existing formatting and recreates it.
If users are not expected to make any changes to conditional formatting, it's best to prepare a macro that deletes all formatting and creates it from scratch. Such a macro can be run when needed or automatically from time to time.
